# Sun Storage Appliance (7110) loss OS

Tags: zfs

We have Sun Storage Appliance (7110) loss OS.
We can not boot to ZFS Application:

```
System update in progress.
Updating from: ak/nas@2011.04.24.3.0,1-1.19
Updating to:   ak/nas@2011.04.24.4.2,1-1.28


Cloning active datasets .cannot open 'system/ak-nas-2011.04.24.3.0_1-1.19/running': dataset does not exist
done.
cannot open 'system/ak-nas-2011.04.24.4.2_1-1.28/running/svc': dataset does not exist
akinit: couldn't mount /etc/svc
Entering debugging shell (exit to reboot)
```

Can you share me file OS of ZFS Applicance ?

Comment: Have you contacted Sun/Oracle support?

Comment: i have. But server not longer support contract with Oracle

Comment: Your server is almost certainly running a customized version of Solaris.  Assuming it's an x86-based server and boots with GRUB like other Solaris x86 machines, you can try booting in verbose mode by editing the GRUB menu at boot and adding "-v" to the boot options.

Comment: I downvoted your question because you seem to be asking for someone to provide you a copy of what I believe to be copyrighted software. Could you rephrase your question to clarify what you want, and/or to request something other than a copy of the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Thank all,

I will reinsatll OS for ZFS successful by myself.
Step 1 : Reinstall fresh Solaris
Step 2 : Install ZFS Applicance (must right version)
DONE.
The system is power on & start normally.

Thanks,
Duy
Email : vietduybk07@gmail.com
Phone : +84909021189